# MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value

Tags: bamboo, msbuild-task

I have tried to build .Net project using MSBuild in Bamboo and in MSBuild comman line switches I have provided `/p:PublishDir=D:\Atlassian\home\bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\AP-BUILD-JOB1; /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` so i got the below error

> **MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.**

[Added job called MSBUild and provide .Net project details like solution file and all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jy8F.png)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure has much to do with Bamboo - looks like an MSBUILD command syntax error.  Here is their doc on error:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8h04acf.aspx.

Looks like maybe a separator issue?  It says semi-colon or comma can be used to separate properties, or the /p: may be repeated - but you've done both.  You have a semi-colon and you're also repeating /p: - so you have two of what they consider to be separators back to back.

Comment: I have solved this error not i'm getting the  the below error..
E:\Atlassian\Home\Bamboo_Home\xml-data\build-dir\DT-NWP-JOB1>".NuGet/NuGet.exe" Get-Package WebApplication1.sln 
error 05-Jan-2018 10:29:33 The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.

Rebuilds build #16
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\First Windows Project
No credentials specified

> git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/pronobeshm/PdftoWord.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/pronobeshm/PdftoWord.git
>   git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/pronobeshm/PdftoWord.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>   git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision b41ae8f43b6760d2da87091f907d2640ff42db6b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git.exe checkout -f b41ae8f43b6760d2da87091f907d2640ff42db6b # timeout=10
>   Commit message: "This is my First Commit to the Github"
>   git.exe rev-list --no-walk b41ae8f43b6760d2da87091f907d2640ff42db6b # timeout=10
>   New run name is '#17'
>   Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
>   Executing the command cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:Deploy=True;Configuration=Debug; %workspace%/FormatToFormat/FormatToFormat.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\First Windows Project
>   [First Windows Project] $ cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:Deploy=True;Configuration=Debug; %workspace%/FormatToFormat/FormatToFormat.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
>   Active code page: 1252
>   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1005: Specify a property and its value.
Switch: /p:Deploy=True;Configuration=Debug;

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
New run name is '#17'
Finished: FAILURE